# Why does my HttpWebRequest return a 503?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

So i am just getting to learn HttpWebRequests and it's functions.
I've gotten to the point where I want to learn how to capture cookies in a CookieContainer and parse through them.

The issue is that some websites return a 503 error and I am not sure.
One of the websites will be used in this example.
From what Iäve read online a 503 error is this.

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 503 Service Unavailable server
>   error response code indicates that the server is not ready to handle
>   the request.
>
> Common causes are a server that is down for maintenance or that is
>   overloaded. This response should be used for temporary conditions and
>   the Retry-After HTTP header should, if possible, contain the estimated
>   time for the recovery of the service.

Which doesnt seem to fit in at all since the website is up and running.
Why is my request returning a 503 status code and what should I do to resolve this issue in a propper manner?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //1. Create a HTTP REQUEST

            //Build the request
            Uri site = new Uri("https://ucp.nordvpn.com/login/");

            //Inizializing a new instance of the HttpWebRequest and casting it as a WebRequest
            //And calling the Create function and using our site as a paramter which the Create function takes.
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(site);

            //Inizialize a new instance of the CookieContainer
            CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

            //The request has a CookieContainer, which is null by default, so we are just assinging the newly inizialized instance
            //of our CookieContainer to our requests CookieContainer
            request.CookieContainer = cookies;

            //Print out the number of cookies before the response (of course it will be blank)
            Console.WriteLine(cookies.GetCookieHeader(site));

            //Get the response and print out the cookies again
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cookies.GetCookieHeader(site));
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: HTTPS is in use. Search SO for `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` and `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`. When you receive a `503`, you should inspect the body of the Response (if not null) receiving the Stream. A message (Html) should be included, so you can better understand what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The URL that you are trying to get to appears to be protected by CloudFlare. You can't use the basic HttpWebRequest for that type of request without some additional work. While I haven't tried this, it may be an option for you to get around that protection:
[CloudFlareUtilities](https://github.com/elcattivo/CloudFlareUtilities)

Answer (score 1):

The url you are trying to access is using cloud hosting which use many security measurement including which browser are accessing the site

for that to work you need to change the userAgent property of HttpWebRequest

request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0";